# Anychart Grid Alternating Colors

Tags: colors, grid, line, anychart, alternating

Is it possible to get alternating row/column colors in the grid?

[see image of flash chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R66TT.png)

Also, the grid lines in the old chart were exactly on the values, now the values lie exactly between the lines. Can this be changed?

[flash chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5F2V.png)

[html5 chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlQ4l.png)

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you provide snippets or samples on AnyChart Playground that reproduces your issue in HTML5? The current version of AnyChart 8.7.1 works well with grids and provide deep customization. For details, check the following guide - https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Axis_Basics#grids

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.
I found the setting for the alternating colors:
`chart.yMinorGrid().palette(...)` does the trick.

Now I still have the problem with the grid position.

`chart.xScale.mode('continuous')` comes already a bit closer to what I want. The values are on the grid lines. But I want the mode 'discrete', with indentations on the sides and still the values should be on the grid.
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcQBE.png
I can't figure out how to change the grid to make it fit.

Here is the example in Playground:
https://playground.anychart.com/cO6ebTmF

Comment: This is not possible using the Ordinal scale. Vertical grids separate categories of the Ordinal scale. If you will use linear xScale and numbers instead of category names then it will meet your requirements.

Comment: I don't quite see why that shouldn't be possible. I have created a better example, perhaps it will make it more clear what I mean.

https://i.imgur.com/n47NtJY.png

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Ordinal scale works with categories, not coordinates. Compare ordinal scale - https://playground.anychart.com/QuGEsn1q and Linear scale - https://playground.anychart.com/ePBrgbHQ. In your case, you are applying string names for categories. So, you can use only the Ordinal scale for that. And while using Ordinal scale vertical grids divides categories.

Comment: In the flash chart we could use strings as names and it worked anyway. I searched the XML and found the responsible setting: `<axes><x_axis tickmarks_placement="Center" (...)` is the setting I am looking for. This also worked with ordinal scales. But I can't find anything about this in the current AnyChart documentation. Is this feature not supported anymore?

Comment: Yes, this feature is not supported anymore as it doesn't meet the requirements of categorized charts like the Cartesian chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer the question.

Alternating colors can be done by adding a palette to the chart grid for example:

```
chart.yMinorGrid().palette(["#FFF 0.25", "#000 0.25"]);
```

Or look at the example in the anychart playground:
https://playground.anychart.com/cO6ebTmF/0

The anychart flash setting `tickmarks_placement="Center"` is not supportet anymore as it does not meet the requirements of categorized charts.